# graphicsmagick - convert images to pdf and vice versa

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I want to shift from `imagemagick` to `graphicsmagick`

But I encounter some issues with the syntax

## With imagemagick

First I need to merge some images into a PDF

`convert -density 300 page_*.tif output.pdf`

And then I need to create a thumbnail of the first page of the PDF

`convert -density 300 file.pdf[0] -background white -alpha remove -resize 140x140 -strip -quality 40 thumb.jpg[0]`

This works fine.. But I want to switch the first command to `graphicsmagick`

## Width graphicsmagick/imagemagick

The graphicsmagick syntax here works fine

`gm convert -density 300 page_*.tif output.pdf`

But when creating the thumbnail with `imagemagick` the output has the right size but the acutal image is downsized inside the image itself?!

## Thumbnail with imagemagick

[image]
https://secure.dyndev.dk/data/voucher/30000/400/30435_eb7e5d0a9df71b2783e2fa89efd9de12fcdb9679.pdf

## Thumbnail with graphicsmagick

[image]
https://secure.dyndev.dk/data/voucher/30000/400/30433_7710d6404534b0868ab8da41dd651e971b70e16b.pdf

Comment: That's likely what a 140x140 image looks like at 300dpi in your output PDF. Can graphicsmagick take a size argument for the resulting file? That may be worth looking into

Comment: Compare the two thumnails.. There is a significant difference.. The graphics version is downsized inside the image itself

Comment: What size is the resulting PDF in each case? (Physical dimensions)

Comment: have added a link to each pdf

Comment: The PDFs look the same for me? And Acrobat says they are the same size

Answer (score 4):

Just hit the same issue, and found a solution here:
https://blog.josephscott.org/2009/11/16/imagemagick-convert-pdf-to-jpg-partial-image-size-problem/

You need to change your convert command into:

`convert -density 300 -define "pdf:use-cropbox=true" file.pdf[0] -background white -alpha remove -resize 140x140 -strip -quality 40 thumb.jpg[0]`

And perhaps add a `-resize "2000x2000>"` to limit the size of the resulting JPEG, especially with high density values.